# html input fields auto passing cursor

Tags: javascript, html

I have seen html forms whereby the cursor moves from one input field to another automatically. It's useful in situations like when you are required to paste in a serial number that spans across several input fields, or like typing or pasting a bank account number that is taken in multiple field inputs, such as:

```
<td style="width: 50%;"><label for="bank_ac"><input class="textline" style="width: 35px;" type="text" name="bank_ac_1" maxlength="2" onkeydown="validateNumber(event);" aria-required="true" required>
<input class="textline" style="width: 55px;" type="text" name="bank_ac_2" maxlength="4" onkeydown="validateNumber(event);" aria-required="true" required>
<input class="textline" style="width: 75px;" type="text" name="bank_ac_3" maxlength="7" onkeydown="validateNumber(event);" aria-required="true" required>
<input class="textline" style="width: 45px;" type="text" name="bank_ac_4" maxlength="3" onkeydown="validateNumber(event);" aria-required="true" required></label></td>
```

Is there some simple way to enable the cursor to pass from one input field to the next so that it will allow pasting across all four fields in one paste? I'd prefer not to have to change/alter any CSS if possible. The validateNumber function is utilising this script embedded in the page header:

```
function validateNumber(evt){
    var e = evt || window.event;
    var key = e.keyCode || e.which;

    if (!e.shiftKey && !e.altKey && !e.ctrlKey &&
    // numbers
    key >= 48 && key <= 57 ||
    // Numeric keypad
    key >= 96 && key <= 105 ||
    // Backspace and Tab and Enter
    key == 8 || key == 9 || key == 13 ||
    // Home and End
    key == 35 || key == 36 ||
    // left and right arrows
    key == 37 || key == 39 ||
    // Del and Ins
    key == 45 || key == 46 ||
    // Dot (Decimal point)
    key == 190){
        // input is VALID
    } else {
        // input is INVALID
        e.returnValue = false;
        if (e.preventDefault) e.preventDefault();
    }
}
```

Important to note: Users will likely paste things into these fields in a format such as:
12-1234-1234567-123
I obviously want to collect the numbers in each field while ignoring the "-" or any other characters like white spaces etc.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this Fiddle:[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/us3m9/12/)

```
<HTML>
<div><sapn>Enter Key Code :</sapn>
<input class="Box" style="width: 35px;" type="text" name="number1" maxlength="2">
<input class="Box"style="width: 55px;" type="text" name="number2" maxlength="4">
<input class="Box"style="width: 75px;" type="text" name="number3" maxlength="7">
<input class="Box" style="width: 45px;" type="text" name="number4" maxlength="3">
</div>

 <CSS>

   .Box:focus
    {
        border: thin solid #FFD633;
        -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px #F7BB2E;
        -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px #F7BB2E;
        box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px #F7BB2E;
    }
    .Box
    {
        height: 15px;
        width: 4%;
        text-align: justify;
        letter-spacing: 5px; /*CSS letter-spacing Property*/
        padding: 10px;
    }


 <SCRIPT>

   $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.Box').live("keyup", function (e) {
             var Length=$(this).attr("maxlength");

            if ($(this).val().length >= parseInt(Length)){
                $(this).next('.Box').focus();
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: Hi Sindhu, please review my initial question as I have edited it to be more concise in explaining what I am looking for. Thank you. :)

Comment: Good enough, thanks. Doesn't do exactly what I was asking for but it's close enough. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this script

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
    $('input').bind('keyup',function(event){
        var maxlen = $(this).attr('maxlength');
        if($(this).val().length >= parseInt(maxlen))
        {
            var next = $(this).next();
            if(next)
                next.focus();
        }
    });
  </script>
```

demo here : http://jsfiddle.net/NW99e/

Comment: Placing this into the head of the page only seems to cause the following error:

`code` Error: ReferenceError: validateNumber is not defined

It's likely worth pointing out that there are other input fields within the page AND not all input fields on this page/form are of the same type. I was hoping for something that could be initiated for the specific four fields without the rest of the form mattering.

Comment: place this script after the input fields (see fiddle). if u want to add the event to particular input fields see this updated code http://jsfiddle.net/NW99e/1/

Comment: Ho Gowsikan, sorry this but I think my initial question was not clear and specific enough. I have changed it (above) to be more concise. Please take a look. Thank you. :)